# What does “distribute with full source code” mean in GPL?

Tags: mit, gpl-3, apache-2.0

I want to use Stanford-nlp in my project to implement some search. But it is under GPL license.

I found the following lines:

"if your company ever make changes to the software and want to distribute it, it must be distributed with full source code"

what does it mean?

Does distribution mean distribute every thing I use in my website?

**If that is the case, should I need to distribute my App Server logic also? (since I use my app server for some validation)**

Or selling the implemented search?

**We sell the complete Business logic, but the search is a small part of it.**

Could someone please explain the MIT and Apache V2 license for these cases?

Or is it better to use OpenNLP?

Comment: How will stanford-nlp will be used in the context of your project?  Is it standalone code invoked through user space?  Are you linking bits of stanford-nlp to some of your application code?  Is it used some other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPLv3 redistribution: when does it apply?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5027/gplv3-redistribution-when-does-it-apply)